# How to select from a specific choice of images on content forms?

Tags: media, nodes

Is there a way to have a specific set of images on an add new content form.

So for example the "article" content type, when setting the fields on the form the only option for image is an upload function so the user can upload an image, I would like for there to be a selectable list of predefined images they can choose from.

Not a single default image, but an option of say 5 images.

Thanks.

(Drupal 7)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[function template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7)

then loop in the variable you want. 
For each value you have selected, you could add an  to your imagetype variables.
Then just display the variable in you node template.